# How to delete an image file from GridFS by file metadata?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

I have an image with the following metadata:

```
> db.fs.files.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4576874577342672346"),
    "chunkSize" : 262144,
    "user_name" : "my name",
    "filename" : "image.jpg",
    "length" : 7103,
    "uploadDate" : ISODate("2014-01-23T13:31:48.155Z"),
    "user_email" : "email@email.com",
    "md5" : "1234567890"
}
>
```

I want to delete the image from Python (PyMongo).

The documentation on `delete()` seems to stipulate that the only accepted parameter in the `delete()` function is the `file_id`:

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/gridfs/#gridfs.GridFS.delete

Programmatically, I have the following values available that can be matched in the files metadata:

- user_name
- filename
- user_email

How do I either:

- Get the `file_id` (through use of the above values if necessary) or
- Delete the file based on metadata fields other than `file_id`?

Additionally, I am only currently testing with single chunk files, if interacting with larger files in the future will deleting by `file_id` or other metadata remove all associated chunks as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's something I just tried without thinking if it's necessary or the best way to do it, but it works.

So programatically I could have the `_id` available from querying on the files metadata:

*Python Shell:*

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> import os
>>> hostname = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL']
>>> conn = pymongo.MongoClient(host=hostname)
>>> db = conn.grid_files
>>> collection = db.fs.files
>>> result = collection.find_one({"user_email":"email@email.com","name":"my name","filename":"image.jpg"})
>>> result['_id']
ObjectId('52e119c47091447a86891d98')

# now use the _id to delete the file
>>> files_id = result['_id']
>>> import gridfs
>>> fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
>>> fs.delete(files_id)
```

Comment: Yes, this approach works fine.  `GridFS` is really just a convention that maps to normal MongoDB collections (by default `fs.files` with a 1:many relationship to `fs.chunks`). Since you are using the `fs.delete(_id)` method provided by the GridFS module, it will delete all associated data from both collections.